# Using .Where() clause inside an .Include() on a linq query with multiples includes

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, where-clause

I would like to get a collection of Customers including several properties among which is the address but only when it has not been deleted yet (`SuppressionDate == null`)

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers =
    context.Persons.OfType<Customer>()
        .Include(customer => customer.Addresses)
        .Include(customer => customer.Bills)
        .Include(customer => customer.Code)
        .Include(customer => customer.Tutors);
```

I have tried several ways to use the where clause in order to filter address:

```
...
.Include(customer => customer.Addresses.Where(a => a.SuppressionDate == null))
.Include(customer => customer.Bills)
...
```

That was my first try but it raises the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException : The Include path expression must refer to a
>   navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for
>   reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection
>   navigation properties. Parameter Name : path

I've also tried with the same where clause at the end of the `Include()` and at the end of the query but neither seems to work.

I'm currently using a workaround which is iterate through the collection of customer and remove the addresses that are deleted as such:

```
foreach(Customer c in customers){
    customer.Addresses = customer.Addresses.Where(a => a.SuppressionDate == null).ToList();
}
```

Being fairly new to linq to object/entities, I was wondering if there was a built-in way to achieve this.

Comment: What was the exception returned?

Comment: Try taking a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj574232.aspx#explicitFilter it gives some info on that type of filtering

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting a single customer you could use explicit loading like this:

```
var customer = context.Persons
    .OfType<Customer>()
    .Include(customer => customer.Bills)
    .Include(customer => customer.Code)
    .Include(customer => customer.Tutors)
    .FirstOrDefault(); //or whatever

context.Entry(customer).Collections(x => x.Addresses).Query().Where(x => x.SuppressionDate == null).Load();
```

That makes a nice query and two simple calls to the database. But in this case you are getting a list (or collection or whatever) of customer and there's no shortcuts. Your "workaround" may cause a lot of chatter with the database.

So you probably just have to take it one step at time:

```
//1. query db to get customers
var customers = context.Persons
    .OfType<Customer>()
    .Include(customer => customer.Bills)
    .Include(customer => customer.Code)
    .Include(customer => customer.Tutors)
    .ToList();

//2. make an array of all customerIds (no db interation here)
var customerIds = customers.Select(x => x.CustomerId).ToArray();

//3. query db to get addresses for customers above
var addresses = context.Addresses.Where(x => customerIds.Contains(x.CustomerId).ToList();

//4. assign addresses to customers (again, no db chatter)
foreach (var customer in customers) 
{
    customer.Addresses = addresses
        .Where(x => x.CustomerId == customer.CustomerId && x.SuppressionDate == null)
        .ToList();
}
```

Not too bad- still just two queries to database.